# Beautiful Soup decode error

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am working in a job and I need to parse a site with Beautiful Soup. The site is http://www.manta.com but when I try to see the encoding of the site in the meta of the HTML code don't appears nothing. I'm try to parse the HTML locally , with the web page downloaded, but I'm having trouble with some decoding errors:

```py
# manta web page downloaded before
html = open('1.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

This produces the following stack trace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Projects/Python/webkit/sample.py", line 10, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 185, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 195, in feed
    self.parser.close()
  File "parser.pxi", line 1209, in 
    lxml.etree._FeedParser.close(src\lxm\lxml.etree.c:90717)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 142, in  
    lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult  (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100104)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 130, in 
    lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:99927)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 294, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored 
    (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:9387)
  File "saxparser.pxi", line 259, in lxml.etree._handleSaxData (src\lxml
    \lxml.etree.c:96065)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 105-106: invalid data
```

I'm try to introduce the encoding in the constructor of Beautiful Soup :

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml', from_encoding= "some encoding")
```

And I continue get the same error.

The interesting thing is that if I load the page in my browser and then I change the encode to utf-8 for example in Firefox and the save it. This work good.Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can't open www.manta.com Is the URL correct?

Comment: Try this : [link](http://www.manta.com/mb_43_A0_19/advertising_marketing/louisiana?pg=2) this is one of the pages I want to parse

Comment: I can't open it from here. Is it for US only? (btw, how to make hyperlink in comment?)

Comment: No it's a free webpage not for US only I don't know why you don't enter

Comment: If you want try a web proxy like http://www.hidemyass.com

Comment: Already tried. I can open the main page, but I can't open your specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the string in UTF-8

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.encode('UTF-8'),'lxml')
```

Comment: I tried and obtain in the encode process another error with encode

Comment: When i put all the lines of the file in a string and the i try to do _ht = _ht.encode('utf-8') I obtain :                                                                 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Projects/Python/webkit/sample.py", line 15, in <module>
    _ht = _ht.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 152380: unexpected code byte

Comment: I see that when you can solve the problem by saving it from Firefox. You can try redownload the page, and before saving into file, do convert it to UTF-8 first

Comment: Yes of course the page is redownloaded before save it in utf-8. But I can't do this for my job I put just for more information